# Is the use of "present during" in "...capturing feelings present during a reading..." correct?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

> Art style and music create a very mysterious and terrifying atmosphere accurately **capturing feelings present during a reading** of this short story.

I want to say that a movie's atmosphere captures or rather elicits the exact same feelings that a reader feels while reading the source material. I'm not sure If I am using "present" and "during" correctly here

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what _"Art style and music"_ means here. Is it _"Art, style, and music"_ or _"Art style, and music"_? In any case, it is a plural noun phrase, and calls for the plural verb form _create._

Comment: "Art style and music". You're right, didn't see that _s_ at the end

Comment: I probably wouldn't use "capturing" with feelings. I might use "capturing the mood of the short story", but I would use a word like "evoking" with feelings. I will have to think about it some more before I can write a proper answer. Here's an example of "capturing" [Short films of Brad Bischoff capture a mood rather than spell out a story](http://www.chicagotribune.com/entertainment/movies/ct-mov-0311-chicago-closeup-20160310-column.html)

Comment: @ColleenV +1 for _evoke._ Another possibility is _conjure,_ as is the OP's own _elicit._

Comment: Some commas are pleading to join your sentence, particularly in the opening NP.

Comment: X accurately captures the very mysterious, terrifying atmosphere present in the short story.

Answer (score 0):

I added some punctuation and articles. I t waws difficult to understand your sentence without them.

> Art style and music create a very mysterious and terrifying atmosphere, accurately capturing the feelings present during the reading of this short story.

While "evoke" may be better suited for "feelings", I would change the sentence a bit:

> Art style and music create a very mysterious and terrifying atmosphere, accurately capturing the emotions experienced while reading this short story.